# 1X5 Matrix Tree Structure PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, matrix, treeview

[image]

I am trying to create a tree view from the database structure shown above in the image. The Database does not have any parent-child relationship. 
What exactly I need to do is, create a dynamic array (parent-child structure) with forced matrix tree structure representation. Where every node will have 5 child nodes under it and every child nodes will also have another 5 child nodes under each of them. The tree structure will keep on adding new child nodes until all the user data is plotted on the tree. The sequence of the structure will be the same as its db retrival sequence (ascending order) Example:

```
Array[0]
  ->children[
  1->children[6,7,8,9,10],
  2->children[11,12,13,14,15],
  3->children[16,17,18,19,20],
  4->children[21,22,23,24,25],
  5->children[26,27,28,29,30]]
```

`
 and so on for all children elements. each node will have 5 children.
Please suggest any solution, if anyone has tried the same.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you need but try `array_chunk`

Comment: And what record takes in what position in the matrix?

Comment: Could you clarify how your example id-name structure relates to children at all?